# Grouping sub nodes in wpf treeview

Tags: wpf, xaml, treeview, groupstyle

I want to group items in a treeview but no at first level.

For exemple, I have a treeview displaying a hierarchical view like these :

```
Organization 1
 Department 1
   Person 1
   Person 2
 Department 2
   Person 1
Organisation 2
 Department 1
```

whith

```
 <TreeView.GroupStyle>
```

you can group on organization, but I whant to group persons in order of a property (i.e. gender)

```
 <TreeView.GroupStyle>
```

is working for grouping organizations but I am unable to set a groupstyle for a treeview item like this :

```
<Style x:key="PersonNodeStyle" TargetType="TreeViewItem" >
    <Setter Property="GroupStyle">
        <Setter.Value>
            <GroupStyle>...</GroupStyle>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Why I am unable to set the GroupStyle value of a TreeViewItem ?

Comment: By redefining the ItemsControl for Person I am able to set his GroupStyle then get a grouping for level n into a treeview. I'll post solution tomorrow.

Comment: Not working, too much difficult. I'll group using an intermediate level in the tree and do grouping logic in viewmodel.